# How to get multiple checkbox values using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the values of checkboxes which are selected using jQuery?

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<input  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try this

```
<input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input name="selector[]" id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />
```

function

```
    $(function(){
      $('#save_value').click(function(){
        var val = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
          val[i] = $(this).val();
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: how to display this? I tried `document.getElementById("#mydiv").innerHTML = i;` but it only shows one result, how to display it with all the checked results?

Comment: @Gosi innerHTML replaces the content. "i" also represents an int

Answer (score 76):

To get an array of values from multiple checked checkboxes, use jQuery map/get functions:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
    return $(el).val();
}).get();
```

This will return array with checked values, like this one: `['1', '2']`

Here is working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PV2e/

Comment: Why not use the first parameter of map callback "_" ?

Comment: @JuniorUsca: First parameter of jQuery's `map` method is index of current element (https://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: what does the "_," in the map function arguments signify?

Comment: @hendy0817: `_` was the convention to mark that the first parameter will not be used in the body of the function. `_` is a valid variable name. I could call first parameter `thisParameterWillNotBeUsed`, `index` or `_unused`, but naming it just `_` was a convenient way to do.

Answer (score 26):

You can do it like this,

```
$('.ads_Checkbox:checked')
```

You can iterate through them with `each()` and fill the array with checkedbox values.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5aJN/653/)**

*To get the values of selected checkboxes in array*

```
var i = 0;
$('#save_value').click(function () {
       var arr = [];
       $('.ads_Checkbox:checked').each(function () {
           arr[i++] = $(this).val();
       });      
});
```

**Edit, using .map()**

You can also use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) with `get()` to get the array of selected checkboxe values.

As a side note using `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` would give better performance.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5aJN/652/)**

```
$('#save_value').click(function(){
    var arr = $('.ads_Checkbox:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
```

Comment: .map(function() always work for multiple values, @Adil thanks that's so helpful

Answer (score 8):

You can get them like this

```
$('#save_value').click(function() {
    $('.ads_Checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpKAR/)

Comment: You should really post the code along with your answer. Say jsfiddle went down, or died... this answer would be worthless. It would also help people find the answer who are searching through google, etc.

Comment: there are thousand's of answers which are using jsfiddle on SO and jsfiddle is the best way to see the things in working manner to provide better answer to question

Comment: Using jsfiddle is great, please do so, but please also post the answer within Stackoverflow! Like I said, say jsfiddle disappeared from the internet, and someone with the same problem found this post... there would be no answer just a dead link. It would also not be indexed by search engines.

Comment: ok i will keep this in mind and i have also changed the answer

Answer (score 7):

```
$('input:checked').map(function(i, e) {return e.value}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try;

```
$('#save_value').click(function(){
    var final = '';
    $('.ads_Checkbox:checked').each(function(){        
        var values = $(this).val();
        final += values;
    });
    alert(final);
});
```

This will return all checkbox values in a single instance.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/TKYaq/1/)*** is a working  Live Demo.

Answer (score 1):

Since u have the same class name against all check box, thus

```
   $(".ads_Checkbox")
```

will give u all the checkboxes, and then you can iterate them using each loop like

```
$(".ads_Checkbox:checked").each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `$('input[name="selector[]"]').serialize();`. It returns URL encoded string like: "selector%5B%5D=1&selector%5B%5D=3"

Answer (score 1):

try this one.. (guys I am a new bee..  so if I wrong then I am really sorry. But I found a solution by this way.)

```
var suggestion = [];
$('#health_condition_name:checked').each(function (j, ob) {

    var odata = {
        health_condition_name: $(ob).val()
    };

    health.push(odata);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `getPrameterValues()` for getting values from multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save_value").click(function(){
        var arr = [];
        $.each($("input[class='ads_Checkbox']:checked"), function(){
            arr.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("Your selected options are: " + arr.join(","));
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".chk").click(function(){
var d = $("input[name=test]"); if(d.is(":checked")){
//
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test"> `test1`
<input type="checkbox" name="test"> `test2`
<input type="checkbox" name="test"> `test3`
<input type="button" value="check" class='chk'/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.