# How to create multiple checkbox handlers in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 2 checkboxes:

```
<form action="">
    <input id="bikeCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="bikeCheckbox" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input id="carCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="carCheckbox" value="Car">I have a car
</form>
```

The events for each checkbox:

```
jQuery(function () {
$("#carCheckbox").click(function () {
    if($("#carCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
        alert("it works");
    }
})
});

jQuery(function () {
$("#carCheckbox").click(function () {
    if($("#bikeCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
        alert("it works");
    }
})
});
```

Now what I want to do is create a `for` or some kind of loop to create event handlers for multiple checkboxes. So far I am stuck at this code:

```
jQuery(function () {
var infoArray = ["car", "bike"];

for(var i = 0; i < infoArray.length; i++) {
    var id = "#" + infoArray[i] + "Checkbox";

    $(id).click(function () {
        var myCheckbox = "#" + infoArray[i] + "Checkbox;
        if($(myCheckbox).is(":checked")) {
            alert("it works");
        }
    })
}
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: used this stack over flow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945802/how-to-get-multiple-checkbox-value-using-jquery

Comment: Do they need to be separate functions for each? Because if each checkbox calls the same function you're overcomplicating this. Can you explain, in more detail, what you want?

Comment: I actually have 35 checkboxes in the code and I was looking for a way to reduce the amount of repeating code. Is that thinking flawed ?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to *do*: is it the same function each time, or different functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<form action="">
    <input id="bikeCheckbox" class="mybox" type="checkbox" name="bikeCheckbox" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input id="carCheckbox" class="mybox" type="checkbox" name="carCheckbox" value="Car">I have a car
</form>
```

> ```
> $('#save_value').click(function(){
> $('.mybox:checked').each(function(){
>      alert($(this).val());
> }); });
> ```

you try to add class name same for ever check box and used the

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to create an array to save all these values and loop these.
And you definitely don't need a function for each checkbox!

Add a class to your checkboxes you want to check, for example :

```
<form action="">
    <input id="bikeCheckbox" class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="bikeCheckbox" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input id="carCheckbox" class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="carCheckbox" value="Car">I have a car
</form>
```

Then you can easily loop like this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    // Whenever any of these checkboxes is clicked
    $("input.mycheckbox").click(function () {
        // Loop all these checkboxes which are checked
        $("input.mycheckbox:checked").each(function(){
            alert("it works");
            // Use $(this).val() to get the Bike, Car etc.. value
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
         $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            alert("it works");
          });
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it by some grouping, like if you want to see only in some of the checkbox in a group, you can use the class name like this below

```
<form action="">
    <input id="bikeCheckbox" class="myCheckBoxGroup" type="checkbox" name="bikeCheckbox" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input id="carCheckbox" class="myCheckBoxGroup" type="checkbox" name="carCheckbox" value="Car">I have a car
</form>
jQuery(function () {
    $(".myCheckBoxGroup").click(function () {
        $(".myCheckBoxGroup").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                alert("this is checked");
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<input id="chk_bikeCheckbox"  type="checkbox" onclick='UpdateIdinHF(this);' name="bikeCheckbox" value="Bike">
<input id="chk_carCheckbox" class="mycheckbox" onclick='UpdateIdinHF(this);' type="checkbox" name="carCheckbox" value="Car">






 function UpdateIdinHF(obj) {
        var id = $(obj).attr('id');
        var name = $(obj).attr('name');
        var value = parseInt($(obj).attr('value'));
        var IsChecked = $(obj).is(':checked');

            $('input[id*="chk_' + name + '"]').each(function () {
                if (parseInt($(this).val()) != 0) {
                    if (IsChecked == true) {
                        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');

                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).removeAttr('checked');

                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

```
<script TYPE="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function () {
       var infoArray = ["car", "bike"];

       for(var i = 0; i < infoArray.length; i++) {
            var id = "#"+infoArray[i]+"Checkbox";
            $(id).click(function () {
               if($(id).is(":checked")) {
                 alert("it works");
               }
            })
       }
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define classes. Use the following snippet to directly access to the checkbox you have clicked.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
     console.log(e.target);
});
```