# TypeError: stepUp called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
<a data-remote="true" data-box_no="1" class="find_or_add_horse" href="#">Find/Add Horse</a>
```

And I do ajax call when I click one the link

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_or_add_horse', function () {
        var search_term = $(this).parents('.sub-middle-column').find('.search_horse');
        var box_no = $(this).data('box_no');


        $.ajax({
            url: "/startup_wizard/find_horse",
            dataType: 'script',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { box_no: box_no, search_term: search_term}
        });
        return false;


    });
```

But when I click on the link I get this error "`TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement`" when I remove this code from ajax call

```
data: { box_no: box_no, search_term: search_term}
```

my code just work fine. Why this is happening and how to fix this? How can I send the data?

Comment: Apart from this solution I'd recommend checking every variable name fits the name you give it in the data array of the ajax request. This can trigger this error aswell.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If `search_term` is an input field you might want to get its value.

```
var search_term = $(this).parents('.sub-middle-column').find('.search_horse').val();
```

Right now you are referencing a jQuery Object containing a HTMLDom-Element but I think what you want is the string inside the search input element.

Comment: `.val()` seem to get only first element when `search_term(s)` would be an array, e.g. from a checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="$userId" />`. Then only the first `$userId` is being returned by `.val()`.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945802/how-to-get-multiple-checkbox-value-using-jquery

Comment: I wrote ***var start = $("#khatian_start_input");** and got the error. Actually I missed ***.val()***. After added it error disappear. Thank for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

`TypeError: stepUp` called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement comes when you forget # sign for(id) and . sign for class. when we can get value directly without . or # sign.

Wrong method:
`- var  email = $('PHMC_email').val();`

Correct Method:

`-var  email = $('#PHMC_email').val();` Or
`var  email = $('.PHMC_email').val();`

Comment: Ankush welcome to Stack Overflow. Tip you can use ` around your code to make it look like this =  `code stuff` to make format clearer. see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that instead of sending the value of the input in data, it sent the complete input, the entire object

Answer (score 0):

In my case was trying to use a textbox variable in my ajax submission that I had mistakenly assigned a value to rather than retrieving it.
`let period = $('#period').val('period'); let data = { period:period };`