# TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
<form class="width_4_quarter" name="frmSearch" method="post" action="proc.php"> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<label><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="re" value="on"/><b>ON</b></label> 
<label><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="re" value="off"/> <b>OFF</b></label></br><p> 
</tr>   
<tr><th><input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value=""></th> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<div id="message"></div> 
</form>
```

And I do ajax call when I click one the link

```
$("input[name=re]").click(function() {  
var on_off=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val(); 
var txtKeyword= $("input[name=txtKeyword]").val(); 
  $.ajax({ 
    url:'proc.php', 
    type : 'POST', 
    data: ({ 'on_off':on_off,'txtKeyword':txtKeyword}) 
  }); 
});
```

But when I click on the radio button,
I get this error "TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement" when I remove this code from ajax call

data: ({ 'on_off':on_off,'txtKeyword':txtKeyword})

Why this is happening and how to fix this? How can I send the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962933/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlinpu

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're getting with this code? Since those variables contain values, not elements, you shouldn't see this error. It looks like that would occur if you attempted to pass an element into the AJAX data.