# JQuery Slider change event and load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have a price slider and want to reload content when the user changes the price slider. However when the event is fired and the load-function becomes effective i get following error

```
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
```

Here is my code

```
    $(".range-filter").on('slidechange', function(){

    var formdata = $("#filterList").serializeObject();
    var attrfilter = $("#filterList").find('input[name^=attrfilter]:checked');
    alert("yey");

    $("#productList").load(
        url,
        { 
            formdata: formdata,
            attrfilter: attrfilter
        },
        function(responseText, statusText, xhr){
            if(statusText == "success")
                return;
            if(statusText == "error")
                return;
        }
    );
});
```

Why does that makes conflicts? 
Should i use instead the normal ajax-function?

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log `formdata` and `attrfliter` to see if they are valid values which can be given in the object (2nd parameter in load function) to be sent as data of Ajax call.

```
var attrfilter = $("#filterList").find('input[name^=attrfilter]:checked');
```

I believe the above line is creating the problem. The `attrfilter` will be the jQuery DOM element object and NOT `true` or `false` which i suppose you will be wanting to pass in data for Ajax call.

What you can do is:

```
var attrfilter = $("#filterList").find('input[name^=attrfilter]').prop("checked")
// will return true or false
```

---

Also refer:

[TypeError: stepUp called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962933/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlinpu/22963071)

[TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536963/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlin)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i've forgotten to map the values like this:

```
        attrfilter = $.map(attrfilter, function(element) 
    {
        var start = element.name.indexOf('[')+1;
        var end = element.name.indexOf(']');
        return {id: element.name.substring(start, end), value: element.value};
    });
```