# How to get Multiple Checkbox data by form as root element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I am new to JQuery. I am trying to get **form data** by using JQuery, first I am getting form elements by fields **name attribute**. All fields values are coming fine. but the **multiple checkbox values** are not getting. I search out many like this post but don't get any answer that works for me.

Sorry for bad English. Thank you for your help in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form-data').on('submit', function(event) {

    var form = $(this);

    var name = form.find('input[name="name"]').val();
    var email = form.find('input[name="email"]').val();
    var phone = form.find('input[name="phone"]').val();
    var gender = form.find('input[name="gender"]').val();

    var subjects = form.find('input[name="subject"]').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form-data">
  <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
  <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
  <label for="phone">Enter Phone</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
  <label for="gender" checked>male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="gender">female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><br>
  <label for="subject">Subject</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="programing" checked>Programing
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Networking">Networking
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Database">Database
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="web development">web development
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="game development">game development
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That's because the name isn't `subject`. It's `subject[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get multiple checkbox value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945802/how-to-get-multiple-checkbox-value-using-jquery)

Comment: @Phiter - thanks its works.