# Getting value of checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have made some calculation using jquery in Page1.html by getting the value from inputboxes using get function and set the values in inputboxes by using set function. I also want to get the total amount of value of checkboxes if check all, but i am getting the value of only one checkbox.I also want to pass the total value of checkboxes to page2.html in inputbox13. kindly help me out.

```html
Page1.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
DEDUCTION: <input type="text" id="myinput1" value="" readonly>
GROSS INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput2" value="" readonly>
TAX: <input type="text" id="myinput3" value=""readonly>



NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput4" value="">

<button id="click1">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput5" value="">

<label>SELECT MENU:</label>
<select class="fee">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
  </select>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1500" >1500 FOR MALE

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1000" >1000 FOR FEMALE

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="500" >500 FOR OTHER

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="10000" >INVESTMENT ONE

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="20000" >INVESTMENT TWO

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="30000" >INVESTMENT THREE

AGRI INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput6" value="">
OTHER SOURCE: <input type="text" id="myinput7" value="">
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput8" value="">

<button id="click2">CALCULATE TOTAL INCOME</button>

<button id="click3">next</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#click1").click(function a(){
        
  myfunction();
        
    });

   
function myfunction() {
var tax, tax1, tax2;
var inc = $("#myinput").val();
 alert(inc);
  $("#myinput1").val(10000);

  tax1 = inc - 10000;

  $("#myinput2").val(tax1);
     
     if (tax1 <=250000) {
        tax = "0";
     } 
 
 else if (tax1 >250000 && tax1<=500000) {
 tax = (tax1 - 250000)*5/100;
  }

 else if (tax1 >500000 && tax1<=1000000) {
 tax = 12000 + ((tax1 - 500000)*20/100);
  }

 else { tax = 112000 + ((tax1 - 1000000)*30/100);
  }

 $("#myinput3").val(tax);
 

 
 
 tax2 = tax1 - tax;
 

 $("#myinput4").val(tax2);
 $("#myinput5").val(tax2);
  
 
}

 $("#click2").click(function b(){

     
  myfunction1();
        
    });
 function myfunction1() {
var tax4, tax5, tax6, tax7, tax8, tax9, tax10, tax11;
 
 var ni=$("#myinput4").val();
 var fee = $(".fee").val();

 var rd =  $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();

 var ck = [];
            $.each($("input[name='car1']:checked"), function(){            
                ck.push($(this).val());
                });
alert(ck);
 var tax4 = $("#myinput6").val();
 var tax5 = $("#myinput7").val();

a=parseInt(fee);
n=parseInt(rd);
o=parseInt(ck.join(", "));
m=parseInt(ni); 
k=parseInt(tax4);
l=parseInt(tax5);
 tax6 = k + l + m + n + a + o;

 $("#myinput8").val(tax6);  

 $("#click3").click(function c(){
  window.location.href="getset-index2.html?tax7="+$('#myinput8').val()+"&tax8="+$('#myinput4').val()+"&tax9="+$(".fee").val()+"&tax10="+$("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
 });

 }
 

});
</script>

</body>
</html>

Page2.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>


<body>
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput9" value="" readonly>
NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput10" value="">
FEE: <input type="text" id="myinput11" value="">
PANELTY: <input type="text" id="myinput12" value="">
INVESTMENT: <input type="text" id="myinput13" value="">
EMI CAR: <input type="text" id="myinput14" value="">
TOTAL NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput15" value="">

<button id="click4">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    tax9 = urlParams.get('tax7');
    tax10 = urlParams.get('tax8');
    tax11 = urlParams.get('tax9');
    tax12 = urlParams.get('tax10');
    tax13 = urlParams.get('tax11');
    $("#myinput9").val(tax9);   
    $("#myinput10").val(tax10);
    $("#myinput11").val(tax11); 
    $("#myinput12").val(tax12);  

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#click4").click(function d(){
 

   myfunction2();
 });
  function myfunction2() {
   
var tax11, tax12, tax13;

 var gettax9 = $("#myinput9").val();
 var gettax10 = $("#myinput10").val();
 var tax12 = $("#myinput14").val();

 x=parseInt(gettax9);
 y=parseInt(gettax10);
 z=parseInt(tax12);

 tax13 = x + y + z;

 $("#myinput15").val(tax13);

}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to get all check box value change name to "car1[]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get multiple checkbox value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945802/how-to-get-multiple-checkbox-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Put different name for checkbox and fetch the value. If you use same name, it behave like radio button, that's why it return only one value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="10000" >INVESTMENT ONE
<input type="checkbox" name="car2" value="20000" >INVESTMENT TWO
<input type="checkbox" name="car3" value="30000" >INVESTMENT THREE
```

And for JS

```
$("input[name='car1']:checked").val();
$("input[name='car2']:checked").val();  
$("input[name='car3']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could do this and use click event to get the value of the checked box:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="10000" >INVESTMENT ONE

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="20000" >INVESTMENT TWO

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="30000" >INVESTMENT THREE
```

jQuery

```
$("input[name='car1']").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).val());
        }
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kb59s0ph/1/

Or you can do a loop:

```
$("input[name='car1']").click(function (e) {

        $('input[name=car1]:checked').each(function () {

                alert($(this).val());

        });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/en9x3sdm/

or a loop like this:

```
$("input[name='car1']").click(function (e) {

        $('input[name=car1]').each(function () {

                alert($(this).filter(':checked').val());

        });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fuxd7cpk/

Answer (score 0):

For what you're doing, you want to iterate each checkbox, and combine the values of each that is checked. It would be best to use `.each()` for this. I would suggest creating a Int Variable, and then as you find checked elements, increment the variable with the new value. You then have a combined sum after the loop.

Consider the following improvements.

```js
$(function() {
  function formatNum(n) {
    return n.toLocaleString("en");
  }

  function calcNetTotal() {
    var tax = 0,
      tax1, tax2, stdDed = 10000;

    var inc = parseInt($("#txt-income").val());
    $("#txt-income").val(formatNum(inc));
    $("#txt-ded").val(formatNum(stdDed));

    tax1 = inc - stdDed;

    $("#txt-gross-inc").val(formatNum(tax1));

    switch (true) {
      case (tax1 > 250000 && tax1 <= 500000):
        tax = (tax1 - 250000) * 5 / 100;
        break;
      case (tax1 > 500000 && tax1 <= 1000000):
        tax = 12000 + ((tax1 - 500000) * 20 / 100);
        break;
      case (tax1 > 1000000):
        tax = 112000 + ((tax1 - 1000000) * 30 / 100);
        break;
    }

    $("#txt-tax").val(formatNum(tax));

    tax2 = tax1 - tax;

    $("#txt-net-income-1").val(formatNum(tax2));
    $("#txt-net-income-2").val(tax2);
  }

  function calcTotalIncome() {
    if ($("#slct-fee").val() == 0) {
      alert("You must select a Fee.");
      $("#slct-fee").focus();
      return false;
    }
    var tax4, tax5, tax6;

    var ni = parseInt($("#txt-net-income-2").val());
    var fee = parseInt($(".fee").val());

    var rd = parseInt($("input[name='gender']:checked").val());

    var ck = 0;
    $("input[name^='car']").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
        ck = ck + parseInt($(el).val());
      }
    });
    var tax4 = parseInt($("#txt-ag-income").val()) || 0;
    var tax5 = parseInt($("#txt-other-income").val()) || 0;

    tax6 = fee + rd + ck + ni + tax4 + tax5;

    $("#txt-total-income").val(formatNum(tax6));

    $("#click3").prop("disabled", false).click(function() {
      window.location.href = "getset-index2.html?tax7=" + tax6 + "&tax8=" + ni + "&tax9=" + fee + "&tax10=" + rd;
    });
  }

  $("#calc-net-income").click(calcNetTotal);
  $("#txt-income").change(calcNetTotal);

  $("#calc-total-income").click(calcTotalIncome);
  $("#txt-net-income-2").change(calcTotalIncome);
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}

ul li label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 85%;
  color: #999;
}

ul li label em {
  color: red;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
<ul>
  <li><label><em>INCOME</em>:</label><input type="text" id="txt-income" value=""></li>
  <li><label>DEDUCTION:</label><input type="text" id="txt-ded" value="" readonly></li>
  <li><label>GROSS INCOME:</label><input type="text" id="txt-gross-inc" value="" readonly></li>
  <li><label>TAX:</label><input type="text" id="txt-tax" value="" readonly></li>
  <li><label>NET INCOME:</label><input type="text" id="txt-net-income-1" value=""></li>
  <li><button id="calc-net-income">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><label>NET INCOME:</label><input type="text" id="txt-net-income-2" value="" /></li>
  <li><label><em>SELECT FEE</em>:</label>
    <select id="slct-fee" class="fee">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1000">1000</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="3000">3000</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="gender" value="1500">1500 FOR MALE</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="gender" value="1000">1000 FOR FEMALE</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="gender" value="500">500 FOR OTHER</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="10000">INVESTMENT ONE</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="20000">INVESTMENT TWO</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="30000">INVESTMENT THREE</li>
  <li><label>AGRI INCOME:</label><input type="text" id="txt-ag-income" value=""></li>
  <li><label>OTHER SOURCE:</label><input type="text" id="txt-other-income" value=""></li>
  <li><label>TOTAL INCOME:</label><input type="text" id="txt-total-income" value=""></li>
  <li><button id="calc-total-income">CALCULATE TOTAL INCOME</button></li>
</ul>
<button id="click3" disabled="true">Next</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Hope that helps.